# How do I elegantly test a method in Go that wraps multiple clients?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a `Client` struct that wraps several clients (etcd and libvirt). Something like:

```
type Client struct {
  etcd    *clientv3
  libvirt *libvirt.Connect
}
```

Once a client of my library wants to close its handle, I want to close both of these. So I have:

```
func (c *Client) Close() error {
    c.etcd.Close()
    c.libvirt.Close()
    // Error handling excluded for brevity
}
```

What would be an elegant way to test this? My current best bet is to create two interfaces, one for each of the two wrapped clients. Those interfaces would include every single method from the two clients that my library uses. That should make it relatively easy to pass a mock of some sort instead of the real clients. This may be the way forward, but it feels awkward.

What are my other options?

Comment: Actually your idea is a good way to test your case. You want to test if `.Close()` is called on each of the client. You can create an interface like `ClosableClient` which has a `Close` method and supply your own mock clients in your test case.

Comment: @poWar I'm not sure how I can get away with an interface just with Close() in it. If I'm replacing client.etcd with something else, client.etcd's type has to be defined as an interface, and that interface has to implement every single method on client.etcd I call anywhere in my application.... but maybe that's ok, since I'll eventually have to test all of them? Or do you see a way in which I can narrow it down to just Close() for this test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encouraged by poWar's comment that my idea was good, I went ahead like this:

I changed my `Client` struct to use interfaces for my libvirt and etcd connections:

```
type EtcdClient interface {
}

type LibvirtClient interface {
}

type Client struct {
    etcd    EtcdClient
    libvirt LibvirtClient
}
```

When I tried to compile the package, I get an error message sort of like this:

```
./main.go:17:18: c.etcd.Close undefined (type EtcdClient is interface with no methods)
./main.go:21:24: c.libvirt.Close undefined (type LibvirtClient is interface with no methods)
```

Not surprising. I then added the simplest possible Close() method to the interfaces:

```
type EtcdClient interface {
    Close()
}

type LibvirtClient interface {
    Close()
}
```

Compiling once again gave me:

```
./main.go:56:10: cannot use etcd (type *clientv3.Client) as type EtcdClient in assignment:
    *clientv3.Client does not implement EtcdClient (wrong type for Close method)
        have Close() error
        want Close()
./main.go:62:13: cannot use lv (type *libvirt.Connect) as type LibvirtClient in assignment:
    *libvirt.Connect does not implement LibvirtClient (wrong type for Close method)
        have Close() (int, error)
        want Close()
```

And then I used that to fill in the interface definitions:

```
type EtcdClient interface {
    Close() error
}

type LibvirtClient interface {
    Close() (int, error)
}
```

Of course, `Close` was simple enough that I didn't have to go through this, but as I mentioned earlier, I'm calling many methods on these interfaces, and this way made it pretty simple to have the compiler help me fill in the interface definitions.

For the tests, I could then make fakes (mocks? stubs? I always forget the difference). Here is the test file in its entirety:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "testing"
)

type FakeEtcdClient struct {
    wasClosed   bool
    failToClose bool
}

func (f *FakeEtcdClient) Close() error {
    if f.failToClose {
        return errors.New("Fake Etcd failed to Close")
    }
    f.wasClosed = true
    return nil
}

type FakeLibvirtClient struct {
    wasClosed   bool
    failToClose bool
}

func (f *FakeLibvirtClient) Close() (int, error) {
    if f.failToClose {
        return 0, errors.New("Fake libvirt failed to Close")
    }
    f.wasClosed = true
    return 0, nil
}

func TestClient_Close(t *testing.T) {
    type fields struct {
        etcd    EtcdClient
        libvirt LibvirtClient
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name    string
        fields  fields
        wantErr bool
    }{
        {"Happy path", fields{&FakeEtcdClient{}, &FakeLibvirtClient{}}, false},
        {"Etcd fails", fields{&FakeEtcdClient{failToClose: true}, &FakeLibvirtClient{}}, true},
        {"Libvirt fails", fields{&FakeEtcdClient{}, &FakeLibvirtClient{failToClose: true}}, true},
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            c := &Client{
                etcd:    tt.fields.etcd,
                libvirt: tt.fields.libvirt,
            }
            if err := c.Close(); (err != nil) != tt.wantErr {
                t.Errorf("Client.Close() error = %v, wantErr %v", err, tt.wantErr)
            } else {
                if !tt.wantErr {
                    // We only check if the clients have been closed if
                    // Client.Close() returns successfully.
                    if !c.etcd.(*FakeEtcdClient).wasClosed {
                        t.Error("Etcd connection was not closed")
                    }
                    if !c.libvirt.(*FakeLibvirtClient).wasClosed {
                        t.Error("Libvirt connection was not closed")
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, you can create a `ClosableClient` as shown below. Since each of your client will have `Close` method, you can do this. In your test file, you can create mock clients which have to only implement `Close` method. You don't need to make the interface implement all methods. In your code, you can use type assertion to convert the `ClosableClient` into specific client to access its functions. [Here](https://yourbasic.org/golang/type-assertion-switch/) is a good example of type assertion.

I have added code snippet to show how you can use type assertion to get the underlying struct. Your mock clients in the test file need not implement Foo and Bar methods as the interface `ClosableClient` only needs `Close` method.

```
type ClosableClient interface {
    Close()
}

type Etcd struct{}

func (e *Etcd) Close() {
    fmt.Println("etcd closing")
}

func (e *Etcd) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("etcd foo")
}

type Libvirt struct{}

func (l *Libvirt) Close() {
    fmt.Println("libvirt closing")
}

func (l *Libvirt) Bar() {
    fmt.Println("libvirt bar")
}

type Client struct {
    etcd    ClosableClient
    libvirt ClosableClient
}

func (c *Client) Close() {
    c.etcd.Close()
    c.libvirt.Close()
}

func (c *Client) FooBar() {
    etcd, ok := c.etcd.(*Etcd)
    if !ok {
        panic("etcd is of incorrect type")
    }

    etcd.Foo()

    libvirt, ok := c.etcd.(*Libvirt)
    if !ok {
        panic("libvirt is of incorrect type")
    }

    libvirt.Bar()
}
```

Comment: Right, but I use many other methods on the etcd and libvirt structs, too, so the interface I specify in my own Client struct needs to implement every method I call on these clients. It's turning out to be manageable that way, though. I replaced it with an empty interface and used the compiler errors to fill it in. I'll post an answer with my solution later today.

Comment: Ooooh... I see what you're saying now with the type assertions. Yeah, that would work. It would make my tests and interfaces look cleaner at the expense of the non-test code's cleanliness.

Comment: Yes. You can always get the underlying client with type assertions